# why my string length is always showing as length 2in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i want to display the string  0..9 as second  and from 10 ownwords as seconds.I am taking the string length to achieve this purpose, but it always giving me the length as 2 for even for 0..9 or for 10 ownwords.naturally it needs to give as 1 and 2 but i didnt figure out why this strange behaviour,I am taking the string as like this`

```
todaysdateString1= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2ld",seconds];
        int myLength2 = [todaysdateString1 length];
        NSString *subtitle;
         NSLog(@"%@",todaysdateString1);
        NSLog(@"%d",myLength2);
        if(myLength2==2)
        subtitle = [NSString stringWithString:@"second"];
        else
        subtitle = [NSString stringWithString:@"seconds"]; 
        todaysdateString1 = [todaysdateString1 stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",subtitle];
```

`Can anybody help me out?

Comment: You're asking for a length of two.

Comment: @HotLicks means....can u say then how can i differenciate?

Comment: You can read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first line, @"%2ld" force the string length to be 2. You should use just @"%ld" or even @"%d".

Answer (score 1):

look at the line number 1

```
todaysdateString1= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2ld",seconds];
```

here you have set padding for your string %2d, which means if your string is of one character it will add 0 as prefix. so remove that, replace it will following line

```
todaysdateString1= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",seconds];
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the code you posted should just be:

```
todaysdateString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld %@", seconds, seconds >= 10 ? @"seconds" : @"second"];
```

Removing the `2` will fix the problem with displaying 0 through 9 with a leading space.

Also, why would you check the string length? Check the actual value of `seconds`.

Lastly, why show `second` for 0 through 9? Normally you should show `second` only for 1 and `seconds` for all other values.

Comment: great explanation ...salute to u..

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using "d" in stringWithFormat, I'll assume that "seconds" is an int.

If seconds is an int, just check seconds and see if it's greater than or less than and equal to 9.  Then base your selection on that:

```
todaysdateString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2ld", seconds];
int myLength2 = [todaysdateString1 length];
NSString *subtitle;
NSLog(@"%@", todaysdateString1);
NSLog(@"%d", myLength2);
if (seconds <= 9)
    subtitle = [NSString stringWithString:@"second"];
else
    subtitle = [NSString stringWithString:@"seconds"]; 
todaysdateString1 = [todaysdateString1 stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", subtitle];
```

Basing your decision on a single, simple integer, might be more reliable.

Comment: Since the format is `%ld` this means that `seconds` is a `long`, not an `int`.

Comment: @maddy The l is a length modifier used to format "todaysdateString1". Basically as seconds is put into todaysdateString1, it's an int, being cast to a long.  So the variable seconds, by itself is an int, todaysdateString1 is populated by a string, length of 2, that came from an int, cast into a long.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Sorry, you are incorrect. If `seconds` is an `int`, then the format specifier must be just `%d`. If `seconds is a `long`, then the format specifier must be `%ld`. Otherwise you will get a warning that the wrong specifier is being used for the variable. Format specifiers do not cast values from one type to another. Try it. Create an `int` variable and a `long` variable. Now create a format string for both. See what happens when you try to use the wrong format specifier for each variable.

Comment: @rmaddy actually it's an NSInteger cast to a Long. From the site in my above comment: "NSInteger %ld or %lx Cast the value to long."  Regardless, we're arguing about semantics, the code I posted should work fine.  :D

Comment: In iOS, `NSInteger` is simply a typedef for a `long`. There is no casting. Repeat, string formats do not cast. Example - use `%f` with an `int`. You get garbage, not the `int` casted to a `float`. The `l` modifier changes the meaning of `%d` from `int` to `long int`. But it doesn't actually change or cast the data type of the variable in any way. It only changes the meaning of the `d` format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do :

```
if( (seconds > 0) && (seconds < 10) ){

      subtitle = [NSString stringWithString:@"second"];

}else{

      subtitle = [NSString stringWithString:@"seconds"]; 
    todaysdateString1 = [todaysdateString1 stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@",subtitle];

}
```